# Using React Router with Switch and can't get the page to render different components when changing routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I created a React app that will eventually dynamically assign routes based on an API call. Right now I have hardcoded components and I'm simply trying to switch the page view to view each of them depending on nav selection. I have my Nav set outside the switch view so that it always renders on the page but when I attempt to set my WelcomePage to the home route as well, it's the only thing that renders on the page and nothing changes even when I select another component page from my nav. Any suggestions/ideas on why this is happening and what I can do to fix it?

Code below

`Main App Component`

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Redirect, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import ApplicationPage from './pages/ApplicationPage'
import FrameworkPage from './pages/FrameworkPage'
import WelcomePage from './pages/WelcomePage'
import Nav from './components/Nav'

const App = () => (
  <>
    <Route path={['/app/:appId', '/']} component={Nav} />
    <Switch>
    <Route path={['/app/:appId', '/']} component={WelcomePage} />
    <Route path={['/app', '/Framework']} component={FrameworkPage} />
      <Route
        path={['/app/:appId/setting/:settingKey', '/app/:appId', '/app']}
        component={ApplicationPage}
      />
      <Redirect to="/app/foo" />

    </Switch>

  </>
)

export default App
```

`Nav Component`

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { useAppState } from '../store'

const Nav = ({ match, history }) => {
  const [appState] = useAppState()

  return (
    <StyledNav>
      <h1>Title of Page</h1>
      <select
        defaultValue={match.params.appId}
        onChange={({ target }) => history.replace(`/app/${target.value}`)}
      >
        <option>Choose App</option>
        {appState.apps.map(opt => (
          <option key={opt}>{opt}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </StyledNav>
  )
}

const StyledNav = styled.nav`
  padding: 20px 10px;
  background: black;
  color: white;

  h1 {
    margin: 0;
  }
`

export default React.memo(
  Nav,
  (prevProps, nextProps) =>
    prevProps.match.params.appId === nextProps.match.params.appId
)
```

Comment: just wrote an answer for ya. Let me know if you have any questions. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I think is happening is that since you defined the Nav route outside of the Switch and gave it a path. It will always end up being rendered on-top of everything else, since you are making the path a requirement and still satisfying that path whenever you navigate elsewhere. What you can do is just remove the route all together for the Nav and do this. That will make the Nav appear on top no matter what without interrupting your navigation. You also appear to not have imported BrowserRouter.

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Redirect, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import ApplicationPage from './pages/ApplicationPage'
import FrameworkPage from './pages/FrameworkPage'
import WelcomePage from './pages/WelcomePage'
import Nav from './components/Nav'

const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
       <Nav/>
       <Switch>
          <Route path={['/app/:appId', '/']} component={WelcomePage} />
          <Route path={['/app', '/Framework']} component={FrameworkPage} />
          <Route
        path={['/app/:appId/setting/:settingKey', '/app/:appId', '/app']}
        component={ApplicationPage}
      />
          <Redirect to="/app/foo" />

       </Switch>
    </div>
  <BrowserRouter/>
)

export default App
```

Comment: Ah I tried it but now it's throwing an error because my Nav element actually relies on props. I have a dropdown navigator that will dynamically render the options based on an API call. I'll edit my original post to include that as well for context

Comment: Gotcha, well i think you can still pass in props to the Nav, just dont define a route. :). Edit ah okay I see what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hmmm I tried but it's back to the same problem where none of the views change from Nav selection, it just shows the WelcomePage Component

Comment: The error I'm getting is ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined
Nav
src/components/Nav.js:12
   9 | <StyledNav>
  10 |   <h1>Comcast.BSD.Configuration</h1>
  11 |   <select
> 12 |     defaultValue={match.params.appId}
     | ^  13 |     onChange={({ target }) => history.replace(`/app/${target.value}`)}
  14 |   >
  15 |     <option>Choose App</option>```

Comment: That makes sense, since you are no longer Routing to the Nav, you no longer have access to params inside of it. It just solely exists as part of the DOM now. Let me try to come up with a way around this :)

Comment: @JCalkins89 hey dude. Can you explain where appId is generated from and how it gets updated, if it does actually get updated? What I have in mind is keep that value in your redux-state and map that state to your Navbar.